# How can I display video in html?

Tags: html, video, playback

I have a link video, how can I play video in html code?

I try with `<a>` tag but it not work

Is have any other html tag can display and play the video in html, my videos have extension is .mp4 and .mov type, i would like to handle it

Comment: MDN Web Docs: [<video>: The Video Embed element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<video>` tag is used to embed video content in a document, such as a movie clip or other video streams.
The `<video>` tag contains one or more `<source>` tags with different video sources. The browser will choose the first source it supports.
The text between the `<video>` and `</video>` tags will only be displayed in browsers that do not support the `<video>` element.
There are three supported video formats in HTML: MP4, WebM, and OGG.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Answer (score -1):

You have to use [video tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) tag.

For *.mp4* video files.

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls>
    <source src="your-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

For *.mov* video files.

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls>
    <source src="your-video.mov" type="video/quicktime">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: .mov code sample does not work in html5

Comment: you can use *type="video/mp4* for *mov* files too. It works. I have just checked )